# extract, from tar file, specific version of updated file

Tags: tar

I have a tar file that has been updated (e.g. `tar -uf backup.tar file.txt`), over time, with various iterations of a specific file (e.g. `file.txt`).

How can I extract an older version of the file, not the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--occurrence` option:

> ```
>    --occurrence[=N]
>           Process only the Nth occurrence of each  file  in  the  archive.
>           This  option  is  valid only when used with one of the following
>           subcommands: --delete, --diff, --extract or --list  and  when  a
>           list  of files is given either on the command line or via the -T
>           option.  The default N is 1.
> ```

Ex. given

```
$ tar tvf archive.tar
-rw-r--r-- steeldriver/steeldriver 15 2020-11-16 18:25 file
-rw-r--r-- steeldriver/steeldriver 15 2020-11-18 18:25 file
-rw-r--r-- steeldriver/steeldriver 15 2020-11-19 18:25 file
```

then

```
$ tar xvf archive.tar file --occurrence=2
file
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 15 Nov 18 18:25 file
```